# Counting task in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose that I have a list of couples `(id, value)` and a list of `potentialIDs`.

For each of the `potentialIDs` I wanto to count how many times that `ID` appears in the first list.

E.g.

```
couples:
1 a
1 x
2 y

potentialIDs
1
2
3

Result:
1 2
2 1
3 0
```

I'm trying to do that in `PigLatin` but it doesn't seem trivial.

Could you give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general plan is: you can group couples by id and do a `COUNT`, then do a left join on potentialIDs and the output from the `COUNT`.  From there you can format it as you need.  The code should explain how to do this in more detail.

**NOTE:** If you need me to go into more detail just let me know, but I think the comments should explain what is going on pretty well.

```
-- B generates the count of the number of occurrences of an id in couple
B = FOREACH (GROUP couples BY id) 
    -- Output and schema of the group is:
    -- {group: chararray,couples: {(id: chararray,value: chararray)}}
    -- (1,{(1,a),(1,x)})
    -- (2,{(2,y)})

    -- COUNT(couples) counts the number of tuples in the bag
    GENERATE group AS id, COUNT(couples) AS count ;

-- Now we want to do a LEFT join on potentialIDs and B since it will
-- create nulls for IDs that appear in potentialIDs, but not in B
C = FOREACH (JOIN potentialIDs BY id LEFT, B BY id) 
    -- The output and schema for the join is:
    -- {potentialIDs::id: chararray,B::id: chararray,B::count: long}
    -- (1,1,2)
    -- (2,2,1)
    -- (3,,)

    -- Now we pull out only one ID, and convert any NULLs in count to 0s
    GENERATE potentialIDs::id, (B::count is NULL?0:B::count) AS count ;
```

The schema and output for `C` is:

```
C: {potentialIDs::id: chararray,count: long}
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,0)
```

If you don't want the [disambiguate operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#disambiguate) (the ::) in `C`, you can just change the `GENERATE` line to:

```
GENERATE potentialIDs::id AS id, (B::count is NULL?0:B::count) AS count ;
```